# Get position of UIView in respect to its superview's superview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uibutton, cgrect

I have a UIView, in which I have arranged UIButtons. I want to find the positions of those UIButtons.

I am aware that `buttons.frame` will give me the positions, but it will give me positions only with respect to its immediate superview.

Is there is any way we can find the positions of those buttons, withe respect to UIButtons superview's superview?

For instance, suppose there is UIView named "firstView".

Then, I have another UIView, "secondView". This "SecondView" is a subview of "firstView".

Then I have UIButton as a subview on the "secondView".

```
->UIViewController.view
--->FirstView A
------->SecondView B
------------>Button
```

Now, is there any way we can find the position of that UIButton, with respect to "firstView"?

Answer (score 230, accepted):

You can use this:

*Objective-C*

```
CGRect frame = [firstView convertRect:buttons.frame fromView:secondView];
```

*Swift*

```
let frame = firstView.convert(buttons.frame, from:secondView)
```

Documentation reference:

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622498-convert

Comment: To add to this, if your view is not always in the same view (say, if you're using this in a function) you can put '...fromView:[button superview]];'

Comment: Is there a way of doing this in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 59):

Although not specific to the button in the hierarchy as asked I found this easier to visualize and understand:

From here: [original source](https://coderwall.com/p/sxynyw/find-the-coordinate-of-a-subview-in-the-coordinate-space-of-a-uiview-higher-in-the-view-hierarchy)

[image]

ObjC:

```
CGPoint point = [subview1 convertPoint:subview2.frame.origin toView:viewController.view];
```

Swift:

```
let point = subview1.convert(subview2.frame.origin, to: viewControll.view)
```

Answer (score 25):

**Updated for Swift 3**

```
    if let frame = yourViewName.superview?.convert(yourViewName.frame, to: nil) {

        print(frame)
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

UIView extension for converting subview's frame (inspired by @Rexb answer).

```
extension UIView {

    // there can be other views between `subview` and `self`
    func getConvertedFrame(fromSubview subview: UIView) -> CGRect? {
        // check if `subview` is a subview of self
        guard subview.isDescendant(of: self) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        var frame = subview.frame
        if subview.superview == nil {
            return frame
        }
        
        var superview = subview.superview
        while superview != self {
            frame = superview!.convert(frame, to: superview!.superview)
            if superview!.superview == nil {
                break
            } else {
                superview = superview!.superview
            }
        }
        
        return superview!.convert(frame, to: self)
    }

}

// usage:
let frame = firstView.getConvertedFrame(fromSubview: buttonView)
```

Comment: THIS IS PERFERCT SOLUTION! THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 8):

Frame: (X,Y,width,height).

Hence width and height wont change even wrt the super-super view. You can easily get the X, Y as following.

```
X = button.frame.origin.x + [button superview].frame.origin.x;
Y = button.frame.origin.y + [button superview].frame.origin.y;
```

Comment: But why i am getting the X, Y value in so high amount like when my X was 0,0 then i am getting with your lines of code as; 180224 or so?

Answer (score 5):

If there are multiple views stacked and you don't need (or want) to know any possible views between the views you are interested in, you could do this:

```
static func getConvertedPoint(_ targetView: UIView, baseView: UIView)->CGPoint{
    var pnt = targetView.frame.origin
    if nil == targetView.superview{
        return pnt
    }
    var superView = targetView.superview
    while superView != baseView{
        pnt = superView!.convert(pnt, to: superView!.superview)
        if nil == superView!.superview{
            break
        }else{
            superView = superView!.superview
        }
    }
    return superView!.convert(pnt, to: baseView)
}
```

where `targetView` would be the Button, `baseView` would be the `ViewController.view`.

What this function is trying to do is the following:
If `targetView` has no super view, it's current coordinate is returned.
If `targetView's` super view is not the baseView (i.e. there are other views between the button and `viewcontroller.view`), a converted coordinate is retrieved and passed to the next `superview`. 
It continues to do the same through the stack of views moving towards the baseView. 
Once it reaches the `baseView`, it does one last conversion and returns it.
Note: it doesn't handle a situation where `targetView` is positioned under the `baseView`.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily get the super-super view as following.

secondView -> [button superview]
firstView  -> [[button superview] superview]

Then, You can get the position of the button..

You can use this:

```
xPosition = [[button superview] superview].frame.origin.x;
yPosition = [[button superview] superview].frame.origin.y;
```

Comment: Adding some explanation would make this answer more useful.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the following code works regardless of how deep (nested) is the view you need the location for in the view hierarchy.

Let's assume that you need the location of `myView` which is inside `myViewsContainer` and which is really deep in the view hierarchy, just follow the following sequence.

```
let myViewLocation = myViewsContainer.convert(myView.center, to: self.view)
```

- **myViewsContainer**: the view container where the view you need the location for is located.
- **myView**: the view you need the location for.
- **self.view** : the main view